# How do I ask someone to join me for a meal in a wacky way?

Tags: sentence

I generally meet many people in person by inviting them to join me for dinner. I want to know in how many ways can I ask them to join me for dinner. It must be quirky. Also, let me know how can I ask someone if they have had dinner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this question will be long for this world once the moderators see it; the number of ways that you could invite someone for dinner is "pretty close to infinite if you put your mind to it".

"Dog Elizabethan" (if there is such a term, or if not there is now) has a bit of a quirky tone to it.

"Prithee, good sirrah, hast thou partaken of a repast this eve? If not, may I invite you to share my table?"

It'll either raise a smile or a committal procedure, depending on the sense of humour of the recipient and how seriously they take their Shakespeare.

Of course if they have a more futuristic leaning, you could always go completely in the opposite direction...

"Taste; the final frontier.
These are the repasts of the epicurean Jony.
My ongoing mission,
To invite you to join me,
To seek out new flavours, and new dining venues.
To boldly go where no palates have gone before!"